# Get Name of array in resources laravel api?

Tags: laravel, api

I have column called ( service_id ) in cards table contains array ids that relate to  services table

How can I show the name of ids .

code of resource api :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'key'=>$this->id,
        'user name'=>$this->showNameOfUser->name,

        'Jobs'=> $this->service_id,

        'numPhone'=>$this->numPhone,
        'location'=>$this->location,
    ];
}
```

The result of get api card :

```
  {
        "key": 4,
        "user name": "test",

       // want convert this ids to name of service 
        "Jobs": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "4"
        ],
        "numPhone": 750123456,
        "location": "zakho"
    }
```

Comment: You need to setup a relationship in the model. More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @KeepoN already did but for many ids how ? for info I trieed hasMany relation but not working :(

Comment: @KeepoN     public function showNameOfServices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Services','id','service_id');
    }

Comment: the  error I got : Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: The result of $this->showNameOfServices() will be a collection with the services models, not the names. You need to iterate over this collection and get the names. There's also a convenient method for doing that. `$this->showNameOfServices->pluck('name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad database design but here you go

```php
'Jobs' => App\Service::whereIn('id', $this->service_id)->get()->pluck('name'),
```

This would query the Services table for any ID matching your array [1, 2, 4] of IDs and return the names in an array

Comment: how can fix database ? what your advice ?